# Uso de ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

Queria saber si hay alguna manera de eliminar los elementos de un ArrayList desde cierto indice hasta el primero elemento.
Es decir, dado un ArrayList de caracteres, deseo eliminar todos los elementos desde el indice 4 por ejemplo hasta el indice 0.
Hay alguna manera practica de hacer esto?

Comment: Evidentemente, se pueden eliminar 4 elementos de un `ArrayList`, pero ¿a qué te refieres con "una manera práctica"? Por favor muestra el código qué has probado y explica porqué no te va bien.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar un bucle `while` para ir eliminándolos, de tal forma que quedaría así:

```
int indice = 4;

ArrayList<String> ropa = new ArrayList<String>();
ropa.add('Camiseta');
ropa.add('Pantalón');
ropa.add('Zapatilla');
ropa.add('Jersey');

while(indice > 0){
    ropa.remove(indice);
    indice--;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dada una `List` listaCompleta de la que quieres eliminar desde el inicio hasta la posición x, inclusive:

```
private List<MiObjeto> eliminarElementos(List<MiObjeto> listaCompleta, int posicion){
    return listaCompleta.sublist(posicion, listaCompleta.size());
}
```

Básicamente consiste en hacer una lista nueva sin esos elementos, no en borrar.